# Stripe 'redirectToCheckout' Throws Encoding Error in Angular App

Tags: angular

I'm integrating Stripe's payment checkout gateway in an Angular application using Stripe.js. The backend correctly generates a checkout session ID, but when I attempt to redirect to the Stripe checkout using stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId }), it results in an encoding-related error.

The error message is as follows:

> Error: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

Here's the relevant Angular service method:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PaymentService {
  private stripe: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.initialiseStripe();
  }

  async initialiseStripe() {
    if (!this.stripe) {
      this.stripe = await loadStripe(environment.stripeKey);
    }
  }

  async redirectToCheckout(sessionId: string): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.stripe) {
      await this.initialiseStripe();
    }
    let result = this.stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: sessionId });

    if (result.error) {
      throw new Error(result.error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

The sessionId is received on my frontend from the backend without any issues and looks like this (example ID below):

```
{
  "sessionId": "cs_test_a1Rmk7mXssO6w13Fk6HYs8ZsbRBNKaOODlBGb3klT3RvyRspHaFLSj113B"
}
```

I have already ensured that the `sessionId` does not undergo any additional encoding in the frontend before it's used in the `redirectToCheckout` method. The `loadStripe` function is called with the correct publishable key and seems to initialize without any problems.

I'm not sure what's causing the btoa function to throw an encoding error. The Stripe.js library is supposed to handle the `sessionId` directly. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or can suggest what might be going wrong here?

I tried reinstalling the stripejs package, also use the ngx-stripe package.

Comment: something's calling window.btoa(somevariable), and it's got an invalid character.  It needs a binary string which means no unicode characters that take up more than 1 byte.

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to the fact that btoa is expecting a string containing only Latin-1 characters, and the sessionId you're passing to stripe.redirectToCheckout might contain characters outside that range.

To resolve this issue, you can encode the sessionId using encodeURIComponent before passing it to stripe.redirectToCheckout. Here's how you can modify your redirectToCheckout method:

```
async redirectToCheckout(sessionId: string): Promise<void> {
  if (!this.stripe) {
    await this.initialiseStripe();
  }

  // Encode the sessionId using encodeURIComponent
  const encodedSessionId = encodeURIComponent(sessionId);

  let result = this.stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: encodedSessionId });

  if (result.error) {
    throw new Error(result.error.message);
  }
}
```

This ensures that any special characters in the sessionId are properly encoded before being passed to stripe.redirectToCheckout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy